# W9 Form for non resident dual-national

Tags: france, us-citizens, banking, uk-citizens, dual-citizenship

My son is opening a bank account in France.
He was born in the USA, while we (English Parents) lived there for a few years. For the last 20 years (since age 5), he has been back in the UK, and is dual nationality UK & US. He has both passports. He lives & works in the UK, and pays UK taxes.
The French Bank are asking him to fill out a W9 form. Are there any implications for this?

Comment: Thanks. My son has never paid tax in the US, he does not have a US social security number, nor does he have a US TIN. He pays taxes only in UK, on his UK income. –

Comment: You probably need to get your son a US-aware tax advisor ASAP, as he has potentially been breaking US law since turning 18... The US is in a very select club of nations which requires its non-resident citizens to file tax returns

Answer (score 1):

No implications. This is a certification to the French bank that he is a US tax resident. It stems in the US FATCA legislation.

Your son will continue filing his tax returns and paying his taxes (if any) in the US regardless of this form.

Comment: Thanks. My son has never paid tax in the US, he does not have a US social security number, nor does he have a US TIN. He pays taxes only in UK, on his UK income.